# Async loaded script causes Type error - bad thing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, yepnope

I am loading a JavaScript using a YepNope. In my case, the script is only loaded in Safari, but not in Firefox. Still, Firebug gives me that type error:

```
TypeError: $(...).html5form is not a function
```

`html5form` is the name of the function I call in the callback that is executed after the script has been loaded. Of course Firefox also parses that bit of code but without loading the script, which is the reason for that error I believe.
Is there any way to fix that error? Do I *have* to fix it because such an error can cause other problems?

That's the code I am using:

```
(function($){
  $( document ).ready( function() {
    yepnope({
      test: Modernizr.formvalidation,
      nope: wpurls.siteurl + "/wp-content/themes/" + wpurls.template + "/js/jquery.html5form-1.5-min.js",
      complete: function () {
        $("#form").html5form({
          async : false,
          method : $(this).attr('method'), 
          responseDiv : "#test",
          labels : "show",
          colorOn : '#000000', 
          colorOff : '#a1a1a1', 
          action : $(this).attr('action'),
          messages : "es",
          emptyMessage : false,
          emailMessage : false,
          allBrowsers : false
        });
      }
    });
  });
})(window.jQuery);
```

Because Wordpress runs jQuery in no conflict mode, I can't use `$` directly and have to re-map it. Maybe that`s the problem? Because`jquery.html5form-1.5-min.js` is written in "normal" jQuery.

Comment: Can you show use the relevant code?

Comment: No, that's a runtime error. It is not thrown when parsing, but when executing the script.

Comment: `html5form` is probably some plugin for jQuery, it's not loaded else the function would exist.

Comment: Yes that's right. "yepnope is an asynchronous conditional resource loader" http://yepnopejs.com And actually, `html5form` is not loaded by Firefox, so you are also right. I guess the callback is just the wrong place to call the function then.